# ftp 7.5 windows server 2008 I can not upload files

Tags: windows-server-2008, ftp

I am using FTP 7.5 created virtual directory, gave user write permission under FTP for that directory. User logs in fine see everything however user can not upload any files. Keeps saying user does not have permission but they do in FTP. I have tried everything I know inclduing giving user permission on the directory itself. ISA 2006 in front of server I unchekced the READ box so I think that is OK (Publishing Rule) ANY HELP WOULD BE APPRECIATED.

RTW

Answer (score 1):

OK anyone who has had this problem I have one solution.

After days with engineers I found the real problem as expected it was in ISA 2006

Yes, you need to create a publishing rule and uncheck the READ box.

However if you are on an EDGE configured firewall one problem may exist. EDGE when created creae an Unrestricted Access Rule take a look you will see it. It looks harmless right. NO

Now right click on the rule you will see another configure ftp click on it.

Uncheck the read box here.

Save

Your done you will be able to upload and download just fine.

Many thanks to Robert McMurray of Microsoft he helped me greatly.

I did some tests afterwords like remove the orgininal publishing rule then I couldn't log in. So I put it back in everything works fine.

So people out their with an EDGE ISA2006 configuration I would check this out.

Answer (score 0):

ISA Server has an application-level FTP filter which will by default block any upload, regardless of the actual server settings and user rights. You need to disable it.

You can do that by right-clicking on your FTP publishing rule and selecting "Configure FTP", then de-selecting "Read Only".

Comment: I have deselected "Read Only" already does not work.

Comment: Do I need to reboot the ISA server HUM will try that now.

Comment: No, you only need to apply your changes when configuring something in ISA; the problem must be related to the FTP server itself, then. Also, to rule out ISA issues, you can try connecting to your server from *inside* your network.

Comment: I can connecty internally tried to mkdir and received 550 error, however I can download and see the files in the directory. WS2008 has the firewall turned off.

Comment: I tried with administrator login could not mkdir same 550 error.